# COUNTIFS using separate workheet and a date range in Excel for Mac

Tags: macos, vba, excel

I'm using Excel for Mac and I'm trying to `COUNTIFS` a date range using a separate worksheet. The name of the worksheet is `"KIDS"` and the column in that worksheet is `R`. Where am I going wrong?

```
=COUNTIFS(KIDS!R:R, ">01/07/2015", KIDS!R:R, "<31/07/2015")
```

Comment: For starters, you can't have spaces.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "wrong"? Are you getting an error (#n/a, #value, etc.) or are you not getting the results you expected? What problem are you having that we can help you solve?

Answer (score 0):

I think it was due to Excel interpretation of the date literal. It may see `01/07/2015` as a string, July 1 2015 or Jan 7, 2015.

This works for me:

```
=COUNTIFS(KIDS!R:R,">2015-07-01",KIDS!R:R,"<2015-07-31")
```

(this is called the canonical format by the way: `yyyy-mm-dd`)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `"format"` of the values in R column to `"Date"` and then run the following query:

```
 =COUNTIFS(KIDS!R2:R8,">7/1/2015",KIDS!R2:R8,"<7/7/2015")
```

**Note:**

1. `R2:R8` specify the cell range in column R.
2. Date `i.e 7/1/2015` is in the same format as of the data in column R.